# How do microcontrollers achieve > 1 MIPS/MHz performance?

Tags: microcontroller, performance

Like [this one](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32117.pdf), which does 1.49 DMIPS/MHz. Even with pipelining there's still only 1 execute stage per cycle isn't it?

Comment: The only typical superscalar thing in this microcontroller segment is MADD - multiply & add in single cycle. Although, it doesn't help much in Drystone.

Comment: DSPs are microcontrollers, and they can have have hardware implementations of Fourier transformation, array multiplication, etc. Do they also count? Does this measurement apply here? Even very old DPSs could perform 8 multiplications on 16 different registers in one instruction.

Comment: There are lies, damn lies, and benchmarks...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DMIPS and MIPS are not the same. DMIPS stands for "Dhrystone MIPS", and it's a standard for comparing different microcontrollers/microprocessors' performances across different instruction sets. The standard is not so new anymore(*), so what the reference processor could do at 1 DMIPS/MHz in 1 second may take a more advanced controller 670 ms at the same clock speed, just because it will do some actions in 1 instruction whereas the other controller may need 2 instructions, or an instruction requiring more machine cycles.

A 16-bit architecture, for instance, will typically have a better Dhrystone performance than an 8-bit architecture, and a 32-bit, like the one you're referring to,  even more.

(*) m.Alin refers to the more recent [CoreMark](http://www.coremark.org/)  benchmark. Note that this is written in C, so actually you're also including the compiler's performance  in the result (just like Dhrystone, BTW).

Comment: But the Dhrystone results also depend on the compiler (it's also written in C), right? From Wikipedia: _Major portions of Dhrystone are susceptible to a compiler’s ability to optimize the work away; thus it is more a compiler benchmark then a hardware benchmark_

Comment: @m.Alin - Sure, I didn't want to suggest otherwise. I'll clarify my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10):

[DMIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone) is a relative measurement rather than absolute. As opposed to MIPS, it actually measures  how quickly the uC can do something useful instead of just how fast it executes instructions.

Like any benchmark it has it's limitations, but a simple way of looking at it is how quickly it can complete the benchmark code compared to a VAX 11/780 (a 1 MIPS machine)
So for example if your uC completes the benchmark 100 times faster than a VAX 11/780, you have a 100DMIPS machine. If it runs at 100MHz, then it's rated at 1 DMIPS/MHz.

Note that the advertised DMIPS is usually unattainable in normal use, especially on large uCs with flash speed, prefetch, wait times/misses, etc. [Here](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m327421.aspx) is a good discussion of the PIC32 DMIPS performance. [This link](http://www.ecrostech.com/Other/Resources/Dhrystone.htm) has some Dhrystone code for microcontrollers.

Comment: Your wikipedia link says that the Drystone standard is already 28 years old. Do you know if there are more up-to-date performance measuring tools? Thanks.

Comment: @FedericoRusso [CoreMark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coremark)

Comment: @FedericoRusso :  The thing about performance measurement is that it is comparative.  If you change your comparison method, all existing results are rendered useless.  Hence the longevity of Dhrystone.